# How to connect remote analysis services using visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-2005, ssas

I am trying to connect with analysis services (AS) using my VS2005 code behind. I am using 
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.Connect(server name) to connect with AS and its working if both web server and sql server are in same machine, but when I am trying to access remote server to connect with AS its giving me "A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running.".

I think its because AS uses windows authentication.

I have urgent requirement to connect and use AS with remote location. Any Idea???

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are your web server and SQL Server in the same domain? If so, grant access to the IIS application pool identity to Analysis Services. Ideally you'll do this through role membership. If not, creating users with the same name/password in the different domains should still work.

Comment: Thanks, I used impersonation and created same name/password in the different domains. Its working now.